# How does the vim "write with sudo" trick work?

Tags: vim, sudo

Many of you have probably seen the command that allows you to write on a file that needs root permission, even when you forgot to open vim with sudo:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

The thing is that I don't get what is exactly happening here.

I have already figured this:
`w` is for this

```
                                                        *:w_c* *:write_c*
:[range]w[rite] [++opt] !{cmd}
                        Execute {cmd} with [range] lines as standard input
                        (note the space in front of the '!').  {cmd} is
                        executed like with ":!{cmd}", any '!' is replaced with
                        the previous command |:!|.
```

so it passes all the lines as standard input.

The `!sudo tee` part calls `tee` with administrator privileges.

For all to make sense, the `%` should output the filename (as a parameter for `tee`), but I can't find references on the help for this behavior.

**tl;dr** Could someone help me dissect this command?

Comment: @Nathan: Would `:w !sudo cat > %` not work as well, and not pollute standard output?

Comment: @bjarkef - no, that doesn't work. In that case, `sudo` is applied to `cat`, but not to `>`, so it is not allowed. You could try running the whole command in a sudo subshell, like `:w !sudo sh -c "cat % > yams.txt"`, but that won't work either, because in the subshell, `%` is nil; you'll blank out the contents of your file.

Comment: @NathanLong: You could probably use `:w !sudo sh -c 'cat $1 > yams.txt' - %`, but I do not know how that will handle special chars or whitespace

Comment: I just wish to add that after typing that command, a warning message may appear. If so, press L. Then, you will be asked to press enter. Do and you will finally have your file saved.

Comment: @Parsa: that has [already been suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work#comment7691076_2600783), and [rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work#comment8471211_2600783): `sudo` applies to `cat` not to `>`

Comment: @NathanLong @knittl: `:w !sudo sh -c "cat >%"` actually works just as well as `sudo tee %` because Vim substitutes the filename for `%` before it ever gets to the subshell. However, neither of them work if the filename has spaces in it; you have to do `:w !sudo sh -c "cat >'%'"` or `:w !sudo tee "%"` to fix that.

Comment: Save using :W and reload the file:
command W :execute ':silent w !sudo tee % > /dev/null' | :edit!

Comment: Note that this trick currently [does **not** work](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1716) work with [`neovim`](https://neovim.io/).

Comment: Quick explanation: (1) `:w !{cmd}` - Executes `{cmd}` with all lines in buffer as standard input. (2) `%` - Expands to current filename. Put quotes around it (i.e., `"%"`) to keep the filename as a single argument even if it contains whitespace. (3) `tee {file}` - Copies standard input to standard output and `{file}`. See [this thread](https://twitter.com/susam/status/1390991411424595973) for more details.

Comment: I had this to work with nvim 0.5.1 using `command W :execute ':silent w !sudo tee > /dev/null "%"' | :edit!`

Comment: Fun fact: vim source code actually comes with an implementation of `tee` though I noticed that it incorrectly uses `void` for `main()` return type.

Answer (score 1948, accepted):

In `:w !sudo tee %`...

### `%` means "the current file"

As [eugene y pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600852/211563), `%` does indeed mean "the current file name", which is passed to `tee` so that it knows which file to overwrite.

(In substitution commands, it's slightly different; as `:help :%` shows, it's `equal to 1,$ (the entire file)` (thanks to @Orafu for pointing out that this does not evaluate to the filename). For example, `:%s/foo/bar` means "**in the current file**, replace occurrences of `foo` with `bar`." If you highlight some text before typing `:s`, you'll see that the highlighted lines take the place of `%` as your substitution range.)

### `:w` isn't updating your file

One confusing part of this trick is that you might think `:w` is modifying your file, but it isn't. If you opened and modified `file1.txt`, then ran `:w file2.txt`, it would be a "save as"; `file1.txt` wouldn't be modified, but the current buffer contents would be sent to `file2.txt`.

Instead of `file2.txt`, you can **substitute a shell command to receive the buffer contents**. For instance, `:w !cat` will just display the contents.

If Vim wasn't run with sudo access, its `:w` can't modify a protected file, but if it passes the buffer contents to the shell, **a command in the shell *can* be run with sudo**. In this case, we use `tee`.

### Understanding tee

As for `tee`, picture the `tee` command as a T-shaped pipe in a normal bash piping situation: it directs output to specified file(s) and **also sends it to standard output**, which can be captured by the next piped command.

For example, in `ps -ax | tee processes.txt | grep 'foo'`, the list of processes will be written to a text file **and** passed along to `grep`.

```
     +-----------+    tee     +------------+
     |           |  --------  |            |
     | ps -ax    |  --------  | grep 'foo' |
     |           |     ||     |            |
     +-----------+     ||     +------------+
                       ||   
               +---------------+
               |               |
               | processes.txt |
               |               |
               +---------------+
```

(Diagram created with [Asciiflow](http://www.asciiflow.com/).)

See the [`tee` man page](http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html) for more info.

### Tee as a hack

In the situation your question describes, **using `tee` is a hack because we're ignoring half of what it does**. `sudo tee` writes to our file and also sends the buffer contents to standard output, but **we ignore standard output**. We don't need to pass anything to another piped command in this case; we're just using `tee` as an alternate way of writing a file and so that we can call it with `sudo`.

### Making this trick easy

You can add this to your `.vimrc` to make this trick easy-to-use: just type `:w!!`.

```
" Allow saving of files as sudo when I forgot to start vim using sudo.
cmap w!! w !sudo tee > /dev/null %
```

The `> /dev/null` part **explicitly** throws away the standard output, since, as I said, we don't need to pass anything to another piped command.

Comment: Especially like your notation "w!!" which is so easy to remember after using "sudo !!" on the command line.

Comment: Is there a way of defining a command for this like e.g. `:sudow`?

Comment: @white_gecko he already did. `cmap` maps a command to an action.

Comment: So this uses `tee` for its ability to write stdin to a file. I'm surprised there isn't a program whose job it is to do that (I found a program I've never heard of called `sponge` which does this). I guess the typical "write a stream to a file" is performed by a shell built-in. Does Vim's `!{cmd}` not fork a shell (forking `cmd` instead)? Perhaps something that is more obvious would be to use some working variant of `sh -c ">"` rather than `tee`.

Comment: @Steven Lu: `sponge` is part of the `moreutils` package on pretty much every distribution except Debian based distros. `moreutils` has some pretty nice tools that are on par with more common tools like `xargs` and `tee`.

Comment: How to expand this alias to also tell vim to automatically load the changed file contents to the current buffer? It asks me for it, how to automate it?

Comment: Your cmap didn't work for me. But this did: ca w!! w !sudo tee % >/dev/null

Comment: @user247077: In that case, `cat` runs as root, and the output is redirected by the shell, which does not run as root. It's the same as `echo hi > /read/only/file`.

Comment: @WarFox that score would really have been more appropriate for http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4376

Comment: This great explanation misses a reference to [SudoEdit.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/SudoEdit.vim) plugin.

Comment: "`:%s/foo/bar` means 'in the current file, ...'" - Huh.  I always read that visually, as in, "0 from the top to 0 from the bottom"

Comment: This is mapping a [command-line mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapmode-c) key sequence which will introduce a scanning pause when typing `:w`. You may consider adding a user defined command to your `.vimrc` `command! Wsudo w !sudo tee > /dev/null %
`. This can then be invoked as `:Wsudo`

Comment: Now i understand why when using this "hack" it outputs while file before going back to vim. Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: That `tee` command explanation was something out of this world. Pure Brilliant!

Comment: The `w!!` shortcut is very nice, but it introduces a noticeable lag while typing `:w` as denoted by @JackRowlingson. Instead of adding a `:Wsudo` command, it seems replacing `cmap` with `ca` fix the problem, but I don't understand any of this. I copy-pasted it blindly from [this related Github issue](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/issues/484).

Comment: `%` in front of a command is a range, it is an abbreviation of `1,$` (see `:help cmdline-ranges` or `:help :%`). This `%` isn't replaced with the filename. If you try it manually, as in `:filenames/foo/bar`, you will see that it doesn't work. `%` later on the command line is a special character, and it is actually replaced with the current filename, see `:help cmdline-special` or `:help :_%`.

Comment: Thanks @Orafu - I updated the answer accordingly. :)

Comment: @NathanLong, I think your update is a little confused.  It now reads: _In `:w !sudo tee %` % means "from the start of the file to the end"_.  In this instance, `%` evaluates to the current filename, because `tee` needs to know that.  `%` only evaluates to `1,$` when specifying a range, at the start of a command.

Comment: @c24w oh, right, nice catch! Updated again. Thanks. :)

Comment: Has anyone else seen the error message `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`? I'm running it from `neovim 0.4.2`.

Comment: Update: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107529/710404 and added `/usr/bin/tee` and now it warns but works.

Comment: `...when I forgot to start vim using sudo.` note that running vim itself as sudo/root is probably ***not a good idea***. Vim is as dynamic as any shell, if not even more so, and can do just about anything (run arbitrary executables, run arbitrary interpreted scripts and plugins, read and write arbitrary files, etc.). Therefore, it is much better to limit the scope of sudo/root access and only use it as needed, for example, for the duration a single `tee` or `mv` command, as opposed to starting an entire shell or dynamic text editor (such as vim) session with root privileges from the get-go.

Comment: @tmillr Good advice! `sudo -e <filename>` is a nice command to know: it runs the editor as the current user, on a temporary copy of the file which is written back to the original when you exit the editor.

Comment: Additionnaly, I found very helpful to add `ca wq!! w !sudo tee % > /dev/null <CR> :q!<CR>` to my .vimrc

Answer (score 117):

In the executed command line, `%` stands for the **current file name**. This is documented in [`:help cmdline-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special):

```
In Ex commands, at places where a file name can be used, the following
characters have a special meaning.
        %       Is replaced with the current file name.
```

As you've already found out, `:w !cmd` pipes the contents of the current buffer to another command. What [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) does is copy standard input to one or more files, and also to standard output. Therefore, `:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null` effectively writes the contents of the current buffer to the current file **while being root**. Another command that can be used for this is [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)):

```
:w !sudo dd of=% > /dev/null
```

As a shortcut, you can add this mapping to your `.vimrc`:

```
" Force saving files that require root permission 
cnoremap w!! w !sudo tee > /dev/null %
```

With the above you can type `:w!!<Enter>` to save the file as root.

Comment: Interesting, `:help _%` brings up what you entered, but `:help %` brings up the brace-matching key.  I wouldn't have thought to try the underscore prefix, is that a pattern of some kind in the vim documentation?  Are there any other 'special' things to try when looking for help?

Comment: @David: The `help` command jumps to a tag. You can see available tags with `:h help-tags`. You can also use command line completion to see matching tags: `:h cmdline<Ctrl-D>` (or `:h cmdline<Tab>` if you set `wildmode` accordingly)

Comment: I had to use `cmap w!! w !sudo tee % > /dev/null` in my .vimrc file to make this work. Is the `%` misplaced in the answer above? (No vim expert here.)

Comment: @DMfll Yes, it is. The command in the answer would result in `sudo tee > /dev/null /path/to/current/file` which doesn't really make sense. (Going to edit that)

Comment: @jazzpi: You're wrong. Shells don't actually care where on the command line you do the file redirection.

Comment: @eugeney Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't know that works. It only works when putting the `tee` pipe inbetween, to. Still strange that it didn't work for @DMfll.

Answer (score 30):

The accepted answer covers it all, so I'll just give another example of a **shortcut** that I use, for the record.

Add it to your `etc/vim/vimrc` (or `~/.vimrc`):

- `cnoremap w!! execute 'silent! write !sudo tee % >/dev/null' <bar> edit!`

Where:

- `cnoremap`: tells *vim* that the following shortcut is to be associated in the command line.
- `w!!`: the shortcut itself.
- `execute '...'`: a command that execute the following string.
- `silent!`: run it silently
- `write !sudo tee % >/dev/null`: the OP question, added a redirection of messages to `NULL` to make a clean command
- `<bar> edit!`: this trick is the cherry of the cake: it calls also the `edit` command to reload the buffer and then avoid messages such as *the buffer has changed*. `<bar>` is how to write the *pipe* symbol to separate two commands here.

Hope it helps. See also for other problems:

- [SuperUser: force vim to write a file](https://superuser.com/questions/694450/using-vim-to-force-edit-a-file-when-you-opened-without-permissions/785016#785016)

Comment: silent! disabled the password prompt so you don't see it

Answer (score 20):

This also works well:

```
:w !sudo sh -c "cat > %"
```

This is inspired by the comment of @Nathan Long.

**NOTICE**:

`"` must be used instead of `'` because we want `%` to be expanded before passing to shell.

Comment: While this may work, it also gives sudo access to multiple programs (sh and cat). The other examples could be more secure by replacing `tee` with `/usr/bin/tee` to prevent PATH-modification attacks.

Answer (score 19):

`:w` - Write a file.

`!sudo` - Call shell sudo command.

`tee` - The output of write (vim :w) command redirected using tee. The % is nothing but current file name i.e. /etc/apache2/conf.d/mediawiki.conf. In other words tee command is run as root and it takes standard input and write it to a file represented by %. However, this will prompt to reload file again (hit L to load changes in vim itself):

[tutorial link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/vim-vi-text-editor-save-file-without-root-permission/)

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to suggest another approach to the *"Oups I forgot to write `sudo` while opening my file"* issue:

Instead of receiving a `permission denied`, and having to type `:w!!`, I find it more elegant to have a conditional `vim` command that does `sudo vim` if file owner is `root`.

This is as easy to implement (there might even be more elegant implementations, I'm clearly not a bash-guru):

```
function vim(){
  OWNER=$(stat -c '%U' $1)
  if [[ "$OWNER" == "root" ]]; then
    sudo /usr/bin/vim $*;
  else
    /usr/bin/vim $*;
  fi
}
```

And it works really well.

This is a more `bash`-centered approach than a `vim`-one so not everybody might like it.

Of course:

- there are use cases where it will fail (when file owner is not `root` but requires `sudo`, but the function can be edited anyway)
- it doesn't make sense when using `vim` for reading-only a file (as far as I'm concerned, I use `tail` or `cat` for small files)

But I find this brings a much better **dev user experience**, which is something that IMHO tends to be forgotten when using `bash`. :-)

Comment: Just be aware that this is a lot less forgiving. Personally, most of my mistakes are stupid mistakes. So I prefer to get a heads up when I'm doing something that might be both stupid and consequential. This is of course a matter of preference, but privilege escalation aught to be a conscientious act.

Also: If you experience this so often as to make ":w!!" enough of a bother to silently auto sudo (but only if owner=root); you may want to examine your current workflow.

Comment: Interesting comment, though one shall be conscious because when the file is being opened as `root` the password is queried.

Comment: Ah! There's the difference.
It depends if the sudo user has "NOPASSWD" set or not.

Comment: Then having NOPASSWD *is* what's less forgiving ... :)

Comment: Btw if awareness is an issue, one could definitely add an extra `read -p "Owner is root. Do you want to open the file with sudo?" -n 1 -r`

Answer (score 7):

**FOR NEOVIM**

Due to problems with interactive calls (https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1716), I am using this for neovim, based on Dr Beco's answer:

```
cnoremap w!! execute 'silent! write !SUDO_ASKPASS=`which ssh-askpass` sudo tee % >/dev/null' <bar> edit!
```

This will open a dialog using `ssh-askpass` asking for the sudo password.

Comment: I appreciate the neovim consideration.  For whatever reason, this did not work for me.  I did find a plugin that solves the issue.  It's a relatively non-trivial accomplishment with a nice end result. https://github.com/lambdalisue/suda.vim  - E

Answer (score 4):

A summary (and very minor improvement) on the most common answers that I found for this as at 2020.

### tl;dr

Call with `:w!!` or `:W!!`.
After it expands, press `enter`.

- If you are too slow in typing the `!!` after the w/W, it will not expand and might report: `E492: Not an editor command: W!!`

**NOTE** Use `which tee` output to replace `/usr/bin/tee` if it differs in your case.

Put these in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
    " Silent version of the super user edit, sudo tee trick.
    cnoremap W!! execute 'silent! write !sudo /usr/bin/tee "%" >/dev/null' <bar> edit!
    " Talkative version of the super user edit, sudo tee trick.
    cmap w!! w !sudo /usr/bin/tee >/dev/null "%"
```

### More Info:

First, the linked answer below was about the only other that seemed to mitigate most known problems and differ in any significant way from the others. Worth reading:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870763/2927555

My answer above was pulled together from multiple suggestions on the conventional sudo tee theme and thus very slightly improves on the most common answers I found. My version above:

- Works with whitespace in file names
- Mitigates path modification attacks by specifying the full path to tee.
- Gives you two mappings, W!! for silent execution, and w!! for not silent, i.e Talkative :-)
- The difference in using the non-silent version is that you get to choose between [O]k and [L]oad. If you don't care, use the silent version.

  - **[O]k** - Preserves your undo history, but will cause you to get warned when you try to quit. You have to use :q! to quit.
  - **[L]oad** - Erases your undo history and resets the "modified flag" allowing you to exit without being warned to save changes.

Information for the above was drawn from a bunch of other answers and comments on this, but notably:

Dr Beco's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237738/2927555

idbrii's comment to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010815/2927555

Han Seoul-Oh's comment to this: [How does the vim "write with sudo" trick work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600783/2927555)

Bruno Bronosky comment to this: https://serverfault.com/a/22576/195239

This answer also explains why the apparently most simple approach is not such a good idea:
https://serverfault.com/a/26334/195239

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with `cnoremap w!!` is that it replaces `w` with `!` (and hangs until you type the next char) whenever you type `w!` at the `:` command prompt. Like when you want to actually force-save with `w!`. Also, even if it's not the first thing after `:`.

Therefore I would suggest mapping it to something like `<Fn>w`. I personally have mapleader = F1, so I'm using `<Leader>w`.

Comment: don't see a problem here. both `:w` and `:w!` can be typed in without waiting and seems to work as expected even if not visible on screen.

Comment: Lack of visual feedback, *especially when expected*, is a great annoyance. I consider it a bug. But to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

So, this nifty command :w !sudo tee % is like a little workaround for when you realize you forgot to open Vim with the all-powerful sudo.

Let's break it down:

:w is Vim's way of saying "save". It's like hitting Ctrl + S in a regular text editor.

! is like calling in the big guns - it lets you run a shell command from inside Vim.

sudo is the magic word that grants you superuser powers. It lets you do things that require admin privileges.

tee is like a multitasker. It takes input and sends it to one or more files and also spits it out to the screen.

% is a placeholder for the current file's name. So, if you're editing "superimportant.txt", % becomes "superimportant.txt".

Putting it all together, :w !sudo tee % is like saying, "Hey, save this file, but do it with superuser mojo!" It takes what you're working on, hands it off to tee, which then passes it to the file using sudo. This way, you can save changes to a file that demands admin permissions, even if you didn't start Vim with those powers.

You can read more about saving edit when getting permission denied [here](https://www.devopsexplained.com/post/navigating-vim-woes-saving-edits-when-permission-is-denied)

Answer (score 0):

[Won't work in Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1716), because the shell has issues asking for a password inline. Under the hood i recognize the C readline() function that does its own weird things with escape characters.

But, to force passing a password into `sudo` we could feed the password into the STDIN, as bellow:

`:w !sudo tee % <<< mypassword`

Warning your password will be written clear text into the vim history.