# What's the use of the exclamation mark ('!') in Vim's command line after certain commands like ":w!"?

Tags: vim

Basically I would like to know the difference between: `:w` and `:w!` or `:wq` and `:wq!`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Besides the situations where the exclamation point forces things, like writes, it will turn a command into a toggle command. So if I do:

```
:set cursorline
```

the line my cursor is on will be highlighted. I can turn it off with:

```
:set nocursorline
```

Or I could do:

```
:set cursorline!
```

That command flips between the two settings, off and on.

I turn cursor line highlighting off and on frequently, and the toggle command lets me do it with a simple function key mapping. Without the toggle, I would need either two mappings: one to turn it on, and a second to turn it off. Or I would have to write a function to determine whether the cursorline setting was on or off, and then turn on the opposite setting.

This works with, as far as I know, all command line settings that have on and off settings, like hlsearch, paste, cursorcolumn, number, insearch, etc.

Note also that the exclamation point will toggle the *no* version of the command. For example, you could also toggle the cursor line setting with:

```
:set nocursorline!
```

Answer (score 64):

The ! qualifier tells Vim to force the operation.  For example, if the file was read-only you would use :w! to write it anyway.  If the file was modified and you wanted to quit without saving, you would use :q!.  :wq! just means force write and quit in one command.

Comment: Yes I recently changed my mapping: Ctrl+S used to be :update and now is :w!, because I have a persistent ready-only file. Would I have problems in the future because of that change?

Comment: @janoChen, yes, you'll get use to `Ctrl-S` and won't practice `:w!` enough :)

Comment: @janoChen: Ctrl+S doesn't seem to have a default mapping so there should be no problem elsewhere.  Your only issue might be accidentally saving over a read-only file that you didn't want to overwrite.

Comment: @janoChen you may have problems with using `<C-s>` in terminal, using `:w!` instead of `:up` should not cause much problem because you hardly hit `<C-s>` by accident.

Answer (score 46):

In your examples the exclamation point means to *force* the action (e.g. `:w!` will overwrite an existing file and `:q!` will quit without saving).

That said, there are many other uses depending on the command, e.g.:

- `:set <option>!` toggles a boolean option, e.g. `:set number!`
- `!` followed by some shell command executes that command directly from the
  editor, e.g.  `:! ls /etc`
- `:w !cmd` pipes the contents of the current buffer to the command `cmd`, e.g. `:w !sudo tee %` (a.k.a. the [write with sudo trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600783/244297)).

Answer (score 13):

It really depends on the command considered. Regarding the ones you have enumerated, it forces the command as others have already answered you.

However, there are other commands like `:global`, `:map`, `:make`, `:silent`, ..., where the bang (`!`) has other effects. Read their documentation:

```
:help help
```

(and we can give the bang any meaning we want in the commands we define)

Answer (score 9):

| example | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `:wq!` `:q!` | do it anyway! |
| `:autocmd! {group} {event} {pat} cmd` | override specific autocommands (`:help autocmd-remove*`) |
| `:function!` | override existing |
| `:com[mand][!] [{attr}...] {cmd} {repl}` | override existing |
| `:set number!` | (override 0 with 1， or 1 → 0) toggle an option |
| `:!ls` | shell command |

```
:com[mand][!] [{attr}...] {cmd} {repl}
                        Define a user command.  The name of the command is
                        {cmd} and its replacement text is {repl}.  The
                        command's attributes (see below) are {attr}.  If the
                        command already exists, an error is reported, unless a
                        ! is specified, in which case the command is
```

```
Command attributes

User-defined commands are treated by Vim just like any other Ex commands.  They
can have arguments, or have a range specified.  Arguments are subject to
completion as filenames, buffers, etc.  Exactly how this works depends upon the
command's attributes, which are specified when the command is defined.

There are a number of attributes, split into four categories: argument
handling, completion behavior, range handling, and special cases.  The
attributes are described below, by category.
```

......

```
Special cases
                                        :command-bang :command-bar
                                        :command-register :command-buffer
                                        :command-keepscript
There are some special cases as well:

        -bang       The command can take a ! modifier (like :q or :w)
        -bar        The command can be followed by a "|" and another command.
                    A "|" inside the command argument is not allowed then.
                    Also checks for a " to start a comment.
```

### shell

| example | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| #! /bin/sh | shabang |
| !! | last history |
| !2 | second last history |

### ipython and ptipython

| example | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `:!ls` | shell command |