# Command Explanation

Tags: linux, vim, command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the vim “write with sudo” trick work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work)

Many times I have found myself in a condition where I end up editing file in vi editor for which I don't have permission. So then we have to copy the content in some other file and copy it back to original file by changing the permissions. But I have found one solution through searching web that we can give command **:w !sudo tee %** and there is no need for copying back and forth. Can anybody explain how this is working !!

Comment: @Darhazer Sorry I should have searched for this topic before !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see...

```
:w !{cmd}
```

executes `{cmd}`, feeding the current buffer into its standard input.

Here, `{cmd}` is `sudo tee %`. This executes `tee {filename}` as `root`, where `{filename}` is the name of the file you're editing. The command writes its standard input (i.e. the contents of the `vim` buffer) into the file, as `root`.

Neat trick, BTW.

Answer (score 3):

You're writing the file to the STDIN of the command:

```
sudo tee %
```

sudo escalates your permissions and tee writes STDIN to the file (% is replaced by the current filename by vim before executing the command)