# /etc/apt/sources.list" E212: Can't open file for writing

Tags: vi, ubuntu-11.04

I am trying to edit sources.list using vi editor but getting the following error while saving the file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Comment: I got this when the directory I was trying to write the file to exceeded its max. disc usage

Comment: As a comment mentioned in one of the answers, you might get this if folder in which the file resides has been deleted or didn't exist in the first place. Look for commands for changing directory or creating a directory from vi, depending on the situation.

Comment: Check that the directory you are trying to write into exists.

Answer (score 411, accepted):

Vim has a builtin help system. Running `:h E212` inside Vim prints the following:

> For some reason the file you are writing to cannot be created or overwritten.
> The reason could be that you do not have permission to write in the directory
> or the file name is not valid.

You might want to edit the file as a superuser with `sudo vim FILE`. Or if you don't want to leave your existing vim session (and now have proper sudo rights), you can run:

```
:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null
```

Which will save the file.

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was trying to edit a non-existing file in a non-existing directory. Turns out, while you can "open" non-existing file and then create it by saving it, this doesn't work with non-existing directory. And now I know about the Vim's built-in help system! :)

Comment: Thanks!  In my case, I was trying to write to a network drive, and my network permissions had partially crashed for that screen session.  I ended up writing out to a temporary file in /var and copying that from another ssh instance over to my home directory.

Comment: Rolled back an [invalid edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1999820#./1999820).

Comment: @Xinus see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work

Comment: :h E212 says:

".bashrc" E212: Can't open file for writing
E433: No tags file
E149: Sorry, no help for E212

Comment: @hello_there_andy most probably you have some issues with your Vim installation (e.g. not existing documentation and/or access right(s) problem(s)).

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai cheers and I think your diagnosis was near enough there... embarassingly... it fixed itself by restarting * facepalm *

Answer (score 39):

### **That happens to me all the time, I open a root file for writing:**

Instead of losing all your changes and re-opening with sudo.  See this demo of how to save those changes:

**One time Setup demo to create a root owned read only file for a lower user:**

```
sudo touch temp.txt
sudo chown root:root temp.txt
sudo chmod 775 temp.txt
whoami
el
```

**First open the file as normal user:**

```
vi temp.txt
```

**Then make some changes to the file, it warns you its read only.  Use this command.**

```
:w !chmod 777 %
```

**Then write the file:**

```
:wq!
```

The permissions are expanded, and the file is saved.  You need the exclamation point because you are editing a root file as a lesser user.

**Explanation of what that command does:**

The :w means write the file.  The bang means start interpreting as shell.  chmod means change permissions, 777 means full permissions everywhere.  The percent means the current file name.

It applies the change.  And it ask if you want to re-load.  Press "O" for "Ok".  Don't reload or you'll lose your changes.

Comment: chmod: Unable to change file mode on vimrc: Operation not permitted

Comment: when using `:w !chmod 777 %` I get `chmod: changing permissions of ‘filename’: Operation not permitted`...

Comment: Use `:w !sudo chmod 777 %` if you get a permissions error.

Comment: Thanks @LamerLink You saved me the day. I was actually setting up turn/stun server on my centos7 machine.

Comment: for me `sudo vi temp.tx` worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 25):

For me there was was quite a simple solution. I was trying to **edit/create** a file in a folder that didn't exist. As I was already in the folder I was trying to **edit/create** a file in.

i.e. `pwd folder/file`

and was typing

```
sudo vim folder/file
```

and rather obviously it was looking for the folder in the folder and failing to save.

Comment: doesn't work for me on macos

Comment: @zzzgoo what particularly? do you have a folder or not?

Answer (score 11):

I referenced to Zsolt in level 2, I input:

```
:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null
```

and then in my situation, I still can't modify the file, so it prompted that add "!". so I input

```
:q!
```

then it works

Comment: doesn't this just quits the file, and not save it?

Answer (score 10):

Or perhaps you are on a readonly mounted fs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DmitryG There is no question being asked here, just a situation being stated. This was the reason for which I got into the very same situation and I think people would find it useful to know about it.

Answer (score 7):

because the dir is not exist.

can use `:!mkdir -p /etc/apt/` to make the directory.

then `:wq`

Answer (score 4):

for me worked changing the filesystem from Read-Only before running vim:

```
bash-3.2# mount -o remount rw /
```

Answer (score 4):

## 1. need to create directory, such as

```
mkdir -p /var/dir1/dir2
```

## 2. you can vi or vim you file, then modify, and save esc > .wq, such as

```
vim /var/dir1/dir2/filename.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Just open the file with -

```
sudo vi filename.txt
```

Then make the file changes and quit with `:wq`

Answer (score 2):

change user to root

```
sodu su -
```

browse to etc

```
vi sudoers
```

look for root user in user priviledge section. you will get it like

```
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

make same entry for your user name. if you username is 'myuser' then add

```
myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

it will look like

```
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 

myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

save it. change root user to your user. now try the same where you were getting the sudoers issue

Comment: This is bad practice. `root` should be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect as root and then edit file. This works for me

Answer (score 1):

Pre-append your commands with `sudo`.

For example, Instead of `vim textfile.txt`, used `sudo vim textfile.txt`. This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the file you are accessing has a swap copy (or swap version) already there in the same directory

Hence first see whether a hidden file exists or not.

For example, see for the following type of files

```
.system.conf.swp
```

By using the command

```
ls -a
```

And then, delete it using ...

```
rm .system.conf.swp
```

Usually, I recommend  to start using super user privileges using ...

```
sudo su
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I used `git rm` on a file in a directory.

I was in something like ~/gitRepo/code/newFeature

In newFeature there was only one file. I did a `git rm` on that file then tried to create a new file myNewFile using vi.

Ubuntu showed me as still being inside the newFeature directory but actually `git rm` had removed the whole directory.

I had to exit out of vi, navigate up one directory and then recreate the newFeature directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my directory path is incorrect, ensure your directory names and path are correct

Answer (score 0):

change the permission for the other user
for that type
setfacl -m u:username:rw filename

Answer (score 0):

:wq or :wq! the vi editor not exit means you have no permissons on the pwd, pls check the permissons then according to that you have made.
example
you have permissions with root

==> sudo vi /etc/ansible/hosts/
:wq  now its work

Answer (score 0):

Open the cmd.exe as "as administrator". That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to edit a Windows file in my WSL `vi /mnt/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`

for this to work I had to install a Windows Addon: https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo

Now i can use `gsudo vi /mnt/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`

Answer (score -2):

You just need to access to Gemfile with root access. Before `vi`:

command:

```
sudo su -
```

then:

```
vi ~/...
```