# FileNotFoundException while creating a file with java in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, file, unix, ubuntu, filenotfoundexception

I have been trying to convert millions of xml documents to txt files. After reading each xml I parse the required content and write it into a new text file in a new drectory.

But when I process some large number of files like more than 7000, I am getting the FileNotFoundException.

Here is the stackTrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /media/volume/data/File8838.txt (Input/output error)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at com.infoarmy.ir.ml.FormatData.main(FormatData.java:126)
```

The code snippet of FormatData is:

```
File newFile = new File("/media/volume/data/File8838.txt");
newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
writer.write(builder.toString());
writer.close();
```

**Here is the strange thing:
After this exception happens I am unable to create the file using vi also. Error 212**

Can anyone point out why this happens?

Comment: Might be you don't have a permission

Comment: Might be your New Volume is not mounted?

Comment: The TRUE error is `Input/output error` as the stack trace show

Comment: Take a look at this question, it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253362/etc-apt-sources-list-e212-cant-open-file-for-writing

Comment: Do you have diskspace available?

Comment: vi error 212 occurs when the file is locked (attempt to write concurrently)

Comment: `/media/New Volume/dataset/GCRIM/File8838.txt` is the target path: disc full?

Comment: Why does your `volume` change to `New Volume`?

Comment: @harsh The disk has enough space.

Comment: @Sudz the permission is also not a problem, as i wrote previous 8837 files there.

Comment: @Aubin Made a mistake in question. Edited the question now.

Answer (score -3):

try

```
writer.flush()
```

before closing it

Comment: The problem occurs when *opening* the file. -1