# Changing neo4j conf enviroment variable has no effect

Tags: neo4j

I use neo4j on ubuntu. I want to have two graph db, for regular use and tests.
I read [article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-quickly-switch-between-multiple-graphs-without-modifying-neo4j-conf/) about how switching between two graph db.

I do steps base on article:

```
cp /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf /etc/neo4j/neo4j_test/neo4j.conf
# change dbms.active_database=graph.db to # change dbms.active_database=graph_test.db
sudo vim /etc/neo4j/neo4j_test/neo4j.conf
export NEO4J_CONF="/etc/neo4j/neo4j_test"
sudo systemctl restart neo4j
```

But when I check `logs`:

```
sudo journalctl -f -u neo4j
```

Config is default conf and didn't changed:

```
Sep 17 11:18:33 pc2 neo4j[32657]:   config:       /etc/neo4j
```

What is my fault? and is another way to switch between 2 graph db?

Comment: I have a similar problem running Neo4j on Docker and changing the size of the cache. Currently I have to pass in the options on the command line. When I tried to update the cache using the configuration file, it had no effect.

Comment: In my case changing configuration file has effect but changing configuration environment variable has no effect. on restart neo4j use default configuration file path.

Comment: you have installed Neo4j with a package, so perhap the `init` script override the variables ... Your solution should work with the `bin/neo4j` script

Answer (score 0):

I think you could not save it properly using vim. neo4j.conf is a read-only file. So you can use this command to save read-only file `:w !sudo tee %`

You can see this question also:[E212: Can't open file for writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253362/etc-apt-sources-list-e212-cant-open-file-for-writing)

Comment: I know that and if you check my question I tried to open it with sudo. so your answer is not about my question  :)