# Can I gain root permission without leaving vim?

Tags: linux, vim, sudo

Sometimes when I edit a file which require root permission (e.g. files under /etc), but I forget run vim as sudo.

After edit finished, and type `:wq` to save and leave, I find I can't, even using `!wq`, because the file is readonly.

If I leave and re-edit the file, all my work will lost, but if not, I cannot save my edit. So,  how can I gain root permission to write without leaving vim?

Comment: I don't think you can, just copy whatever you have in it, close vim, run with sudo and paste. edit: or do as darryn.ten answered.

Comment: @darryn.ten There are no 'correct' answers. Just 'helpful' and/or 'accepted' answers :)

Comment: @sehe - semantics... accepted then

Comment: The easiest solution is of course to use Emacs, which won't allow to edit a file when you don't have the permission to save it in the first place. *grins, ducks and runs*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To force a save use the following command

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

It will prompt you for your password.

Comment: I can never remember this when I need it  :/

Comment: I forced myself to remember it as I use it quite regularly

Comment: @Michael:  A common workaround used in order to get rid of the necessity to remember a complex command is to create a custom one: `:command! W w !sudo tee % >/dev/null`.

Comment: I have test it, and it work as expected, thank you very much. Can you tell me why I should this command, what dose it mean?

Comment: I have bound this to w!! in my vimrc, but often ssh to boxes that don't have my vimrc available.

Comment: @Andy:  See the question "[How does the vim “write with sudo” trick work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2600783/254635)"

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned trick with `tee` is nice; if you need this often I'd recommend the [SudoEdit plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2709), which offers a `:SudoWrite` command (and even a `sudo:` protocol handler).