# How can I get super-user privilege within vi?

Tags: linux, vim, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the vim “write with sudo” trick work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work)

This situation always happen: I try to `vi` a configuration file but I forget to add `sudo` before it, and when I try to save it, `vi` prompt me that this file is read only.

How can I change to super-user privilege without get out of `vi` and re-edit that file?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in vi and vim:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmap w!! %!sudo tee > /dev/null %
```

Add the line in ~ /. Vimrc and do: w!! to keep with sudo

Answer (score -2):

Usually I save it in temp with **:w /tmp/foo.txt** and then sudo cp.