# vims cmd to tee to persistent python 'watchdog' process

Tags: python, vim

I would like to run a command from vim, to spawn a persistent python watchdog process.
The normal command is `pycco -w somefile.py`.

I have tried running tee from vim.

`:!pycco -w | tee % | w %` runs the python watchdog command but does not return to vim.

Reversed, `:w tee % | !pycco -w %` generates error 
`e172 only 1 file name allowed`

A commentor in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work), mentions using `sh -c ">"` rather than tee.
(I generate trailing character error when trying sh).

how to tee process using vim {cmd}?

Comment: Hi, thanks, however this writes the shell output to the file cursor position.  Any updates do not show up either.  The process is running (checked psgrep) though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but you might benefit from [vimux](https://github.com/benmills/vimux), a plugin for Vim that allows you to work with Tmux from inside of Vim.