# Why can't I save a VI file after entering data?

Tags: linux, file, vi

I am new to linux, when I typed "vi FILE1" I was able to open VI editor. I added some data and I want to save the file and I tried :w but it threw me an error.

"file1" E212: Can't open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue

why I am not able to save it?

The directory in which I am creating file has following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 pentaho pentaho 4096 Mar 12  2013 master
```

I am logging using root user and password.

Output of `mount` command :

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw)

    proc on /proc type proc (rw)
    sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
    devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
    tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
    /dev/sdb1 on /etl type ext4 (rw)
    /dev/sdc1 on /oracle type ext4 (rw)
    /dev/sdd1 on /export type ext4 (rw)
    none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
    sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
```

Comment: check your file permission.

Comment: I have updated the question. kindly help me in that . I am creating the file in master directory which has permission stated above.

Comment: There are a few possibilities.  You were in a directory on a read-only mounted file-system.  The file belongs to a user other than root, and is in a gvfs directory, the file is on an nfs mounted file-system, and root_squash is turned on, the file doesn't have write-permissions set ...   the list goes on and on ...

Comment: how to check all this. kindlyhelp me resolving this issue.

Comment: file-system full?  what does df says?

Answer (score 5):

You can also get this error if the directory you are trying to save to does not exist.  Even the root user will get this error.

Comment: And how do you solve this without saving to temporary file?

Comment: For example, if your current working directory was deleted and re-created since you switched to it, you will need to `cd .. ; cd myWorkingDir` before you can use `vi newFile` again.

Answer (score 3):

When you log in linux with your common user, you are logged with the user you created, but you are not superuser (you do not have all permissions). To execute a program with root priviliges (and therefore have all permissions), you have to add the command sudo. So you should run: `$> sudo vi FILE1`. This will ask you for the password and then you use vi normally

Comment: "I am logging using root user and password."

Comment: can you use $>touch FILE1 to check if you have permission to create files?

Comment: I can create files in other directory bit not in the master directory

Comment: try `$>sudo chattr -i DIRECTORY_PATH`, as the directory may be set as immutable

Comment: touch test
touch: cannot touch `test': Read-only file system

Comment: Worth noting `:w !sudo tee %` as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue in vi, try to create directory manually and edit the file. May be you don't have access to create directory/file.