# How can I save a file I opened in vim as the wrong user?

Tags: vim, vi

This happens to me all the time. I login as a normal user and start editing a file using vim. After editing is done, when I try to save the file, I don't have enough permission to save the file. I have to close the file, login as root and start editing again. Below is the given error in vim:

```
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
```

Or in plain vi:

```
File is read only
```

Is there a way to save without leaving the editor?

Comment: I avoid the problem with an autocmd that checks if 'readonly' is set after loading the file, and then setting 'nomodifiable' if the file is readonly to prevent me accidentally editing the file.

Comment: `:wq!` worked for me

Comment: @Anup : this should be the answer. Thanks !!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try the below command

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

Explanation

- :w – write
- !sudo – call shell sudo command
- tee – the output of write (:w) command is redirected using tee
- % – current file name

[More info](http://dasunhegoda.com/tutorial-in-vim-editor-introduction-vim/510/)

Comment: Related post: [How does the vim “write with sudo” trick work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2600783/438329). If you have Tim Pope's [eunuch.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) then you can do `:SudoWrite`

Comment: Also, a good similar alternative with explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237738/670521

Answer (score 1):

E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)

press Esc, then type :qa! and press Enter

Answer (score 1):

Just simply type your command with `sudo` like `sudo vi filename.txt`.

Then, hit `i`, edit what you want to change and hit Esc.
Then `:wq`

Answer (score 1):

```
:w /tmp/xyz
:q!
```

/tmp should always be writeable to erveryone.
And then mv or cp the file /tmp/xyz as the correct user to where your original file was

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).